# Get selected text when in any application on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, appkit

I'm trying to get the selected text when the user presses a global shortcut. My app should read the text which is currently selected no matter if the currently focused app is chrome, safari or Microsoft Word.

I'm trying to do this using an AppleScript which does this using a hack with the clipboard. This doesn't work in all applications though.

```swift
func readSelectedText() {
    let script = """
    -- Back up clipboard contents:
    set savedClipboard to the clipboard

    -- Copy selected text to clipboard:
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {command down}
    delay 1 -- Without this, the clipboard may have stale data.

    set theSelectedText to the clipboard

    delay 1 -- Without this delay, may restore clipboard before pasting.

    -- Restore clipboard:
    set the clipboard to savedClipboard

    return theSelectedText
    """

    var error: NSDictionary?
    if let appleScript = NSAppleScript(source: script), let output = appleScript.executeAndReturnError(&error).stringValue {
        print("Selected text:", output)
    } else {
        print("AppleScriptError: \(String(describing: error))")
    }

}
```

Is there a robust way to do this in any app?

Comment: Are you talking about NSServices?

Comment: `I'm trying to get the selected text ...`, you could use
 `NSPasteboard.general.string(forType: .string)` to get the selected text,
 see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard

Comment: The data is put on the global pasteboard when an app goes to the background and is pulled from the global pasteboard when an app becomes the frontmost app. You might try an app switch in addition to the delay.

Comment: Is any app every app or a specific app? Have you tried getting the text with the Accessibility API?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the accessibility APIs to do this:

```
import ApplicationServices
import Cocoa

func getSelectedText() -> String? {
    let systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()

    var selectedTextValue: AnyObject?
    let errorCode = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute as CFString, &selectedTextValue)
    
    if errorCode == .success {
        let selectedTextElement = selectedTextValue as! AXUIElement
        var selectedText: AnyObject?
        let textErrorCode = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(selectedTextElement, kAXSelectedTextAttribute as CFString, &selectedText)
        
        if textErrorCode == .success, let selectedTextString = selectedText as? String {
            return selectedTextString
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

This requires setting `Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description` in Info.plist and setting `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` to have `com.apple.systemevents`.

Comment: Do we need to release anything? I always see CFRelease function on older Objective-C examples.

Comment: working greatly in 2023 on macOS 14.0

Comment: When I use cmd+a or select a long text in vscode. This won't work. Any idea?

Comment: Can someone write a step-by-step on how to use this? I have no idea where to write or call it from. :/

Comment: @paulodiovani You can test it out in XCode playground. Open XCode, create a new MacOS Playground, past the code above. You can print the result via `print("selectedText =", getSelectedText() ?? "none")`.

Comment: Am new two macOS and XCode development. How to achieve the second part? "This requires setting Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description in Info.plist and setting com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events to have com.apple.systemevents."

Comment: Same here. No idea how to define the Info.plist -- XCode doesn't seem to create it automatically for command line tools.