# How to Select Last N Characters in Active Text Field Across macOS on Specific Key Binding?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm developing a native macOS application and need assistance with a feature where pressing a specific key combination (e.g., CTRL + S) captures the last N characters (for instance, 200 characters) from whatever text field is active, regardless of the application. This feature should work across all text input fields in any application running on macOS.

---

I am aware of this solution, where the text that the user has selected manually can be processed by calling the below function ([Get selected text when in any application on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009610/get-selected-text-when-in-any-application-on-macos))

```
import ApplicationServices
import Cocoa

func getSelectedText() -> String? {
    let systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()

    var selectedTextValue: AnyObject?
    let errorCode = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute as CFString, &selectedTextValue)
    
    if errorCode == .success {
        let selectedTextElement = selectedTextValue as! AXUIElement
        var selectedText: AnyObject?
        let textErrorCode = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(selectedTextElement, kAXSelectedTextAttribute as CFString, &selectedText)
        
        if textErrorCode == .success, let selectedTextString = selectedText as? String {
            return selectedTextString
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

So essentially, I need a mechanism that auto-selects previous N words/chars when a certain key-binding was used and then calls the above function `getSelectedText()`.

I am thankful for any help regarding this matter!

Comment: What is the question, how to detect a key combination, how to get text from another app, how to select text in another app or how to add something to Info.plist? Ask one question per question please.

Comment: @Willeke, sure, I will clarify. I need to know how to auto-transfer N chars/words of text for further processing whenever the user presses a user-specific key-binding. In my question, I detailed how I have a solution to process already selected text. My problem is that I don't want the user to manually select text, but instead pick N words he has previously written automatically when he performs a shortcut with a pre-defined key-binding. Is that clearer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Text in Webkit applications via macOS accessibility API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72478435/select-text-in-webkit-applications-via-macos-accessibility-api)

Comment: @user21161308, you haven't clarified if you need help 1) **Listening for the key event** or 2) **Manipulating the text selection**. These are 2 distinct steps that are best handled in 2 different SO questions. For 1) you can use `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents` or the older Carbon API. For 2), I haven't got that working either. Setting `AXSelectedTextRange` seems to work with `AXTextField` but not with `AXTextArea` in my attempts.